Как заполнить поля в DbGridEh?
мне нужно добавить запись в базу данных через DbGridEh. Заполняю его через OraDataSource->OraQuery. На событие DBGridEh1KeyDown записан код:
if (key=VK_INSERT) and not(DBGridEh1.ReadOnly) then OraQuery1.Append;

При нажатии кнопки добавляется пустая запись, но заполнить ее не получается.
Внутри объекта OraQuery в разделе Update SQL's в Statement Type Insert также написан код:
insert into reestr_sout
(id_sout,registr_nmb,date_registr,nmb_kart,id_podr,id_prof,date_from,date_to,id_holder)
values(:id_sout,:registr_nmb,:date_registr,:nmb_kart,:id_podr,:id_prof,:date_from,:date_to,:id_holder)

что нужно еще сделать, чтобы можно было прямо внутри DbGridEh заполнить поля и они записались в базу данных?

Проблема была в свойстве объекта DbgridEh->Options->dgEditing оно стояло в значении false, нужно чтобы оно было в значении true. Также в DbgridEh->Options есть свойство dgRowSelect и если оно в значении true то dgEditing будет в значении false и поменять его нельзя. Если поставить dgRowSelect в значение false то dgEditing можно будет поставить в значение true
